# Adding a Swift framework to an OpenFrameworks (C++) Project

Tags: c++, xcode, swift, objective-c++, openframeworks

I'm trying to add [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io) (a Swift audio framework I'm involved with) to an [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/) project. I'm able to add the framework by changing the `main.m file` to `main.mm`, and the `ofApp.cpp` file to `ofApp.mm` (switching from C++ to Objective-C++ since I'm only working on a Mac).

I have a simple instrument defined in my Swift file (`Oscillator.swift`). I'm able to access this file through the auto-generated header Xcode made for accessing Swift code, myProjectDebug-Swift.h. If I import that file in main.mm, I'm able to successfully create an instance of my oscillator, and hear it on startup. All groovy so far.

HOWEVER, if I do the same thing in `ofApp.mm`, I get build errors as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why I would be able to access a Swift file in my `main.mm` file, but not the `ofApp.mm` file??

Below is the code in my main.mm file that is working fine:

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofApp.h"
#include "ofxGui.h"
#include "myProjectDebug-Swift.h"

//========================================================================

int main( ){
     OscillatorInstrument *instrument = [[OscillatorInstrument alloc] init];
}
```

And, this is the code in my `ofApp.mm` file that does compile:

```
#include "ofApp.h"
#import "myProjectDebug-Swift.h"

void ofApp::setup(){

     OscillatorInstrument *instrument = [[OscillatorInstrument alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: The problem ended up being that I had forgotten to mark the files as being Objective-C++ source types. I'm going to be writing up a tutorial on this at some point.